# create tuple of hashmaps from arraylist - Java

Tags: java, hashmap, tuples

I am trying to iterate the following data I have stored in an ArrayList in Java. This ArrayList is called "T":

```
outlook    temperature    humidity    windy    play
sunny      hot            high        False    No
overcast   hot            low         True     No
rainy      cool           normal      True     No
sunny      hot            normal      False    Yes
```

I want to obtain a chart like this for each column, so that I get the number of occurrences of each column grouped by Yes or No (play column):

```
outlook          play
            Yes        No
sunny        1          1
overcast     1          1
rainy        0          1
```

I really don't know much about Java. But, I have seen that I need to use a tuple of hashmaps for this purpose, as I need several attributes to be grouped like this (always compared to the "play" column).

My code so far is this (but I am sure it does not work). Can anyone help me please? Thanks

```
Map<String, Integer> mapOutput = new HashMap();

    for (List<String> input: T) { 

        if (mapOutput.containsKey(input.get(input.size()-1))) { 
            mapOutput.put(input.get(input.size()-1), mapOutput.get(input.get(input.size()-1)) + 1);

        } else {
            mapOutput.put(input.get(input.size()-1), 1);

        }

    }
```

Comment: Each line of your input is an element in T?

Comment: a tuple of hashmaps, where the only keys are Yes/No, seems like a pretty ridiculous way to store this... I suggest a hashmap keyed by outlook and storing PlayData, a tuple of two ints. Except its a custom class instead of a tuple, because Java doesnt have tuples.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("I am sure it does not work" ) must include a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [mcve]

Comment: Please clarify a few things... 1. Is your tabular data `T` a list of list of strings? 2. How is the grouping criteria for i.e. `outlook` (first column)? Do you want to count how many occurrences of i.e. `sunny` appear with `play=yes` and with `play=no`, and the same for all the other values in the `outlook` column? If true, then your sample output doesn't make sense (`overcast` appears with `1` in `Yes`, but it should be `0`). Please provide sample input and sample output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to make some wild guesses here, because neither the initial data structure nor the desired output is clear from the question:

1. The tabular data represented by `T` is a `List<List<String>>`
2. You want to group by each column, counting how many rows appear with value equal to `Yes` and how many rows appear with value equal to `No`, for the `play` column

If these assumptions hold true, you could achieve it as follows:

```
Map<String, Map<Boolean, Long>> result = T.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        input -> input.get(columnIndex),
        Collectors.partitioningBy(
            input -> "Yes".equals(input.get(input.size() - 1)),
            Collectors.counting())));
```

Where `columnIndex` is a parameter and its value is `0` for `outlook`, `1` for `temperature`, etc, i.e. it matches the index of the column to group by.

This assumes that the `play` column is always the last one for each row and that there are neither null nor missing values. Strings must also be trimmed, i.e. without spaces, tabs, etc.